# Convert SOAP multiref to java Object

Tags: java, soap

May you please help me to transform the following SOAP request data to java Collection, i have tried but not getting expected result. You may see as reference below in second part which i have transformed from Java to SOAP request.

```
<multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Map" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">orderIncrementId</key>
                    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">ORD-4426</value>
                </item>
                <multiRef href="#id3"/>
            </multiRef>

            <multiRef id="id3" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:Map" xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">order_item_id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1229</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">qty</key>
                    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value>
                </item>
            </multiRef>
```

The following xml generated from java as stated below.

```
Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
header.put("OrderIncrementId", "ORD-4426");

Map<String, String> detail_1= new HashMap<String, String>();
details.put("order_item_id", "1229");
details.put("qty", "1");

List<Map<String,String>> details = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
details.add(detail_1);

List<Object> finalList = new ArrayList<Objec>();
finalList.add(header);
finalList.add(details);

<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <multiRef href="#id1"/>
            <multiRef href="#id2"/>
        </multiRef>
        <multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <multiRef href="#id3"/>
        </multiRef>
        <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Map" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">orderIncrementId</key>
                <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">ORD-4426</value>
            </item>
        </multiRef>
        <multiRef id="id3" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:Map" xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">order_item_id</key>
                <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1229</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">qty</key>
                <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1</value>
            </item>
        </multiRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any straight answers available for your issue.
But you can try with Jaxb (Since the multi ref is an xml). You should be able to convert into java objects and from there you can extract objects whichever required.

Comment: Hi Kartik, Please see once again. I have updated my question.